# when setting the XBee SM parameter to 1 (Pin Hibernate) does it still act as a router?

Tags: xbee

Im currently working with XBee S2. The product datasheet states that xbee's acting as routers cannot sleep, but when using a Router Firmware i can still configure the SM parameter. When setting it to 1 (Pin Hibernate), does it keep it's routing capabilities (when on wake state, of course) or does it work as "end device" (no routing capabilities)?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-Datasheet.pdf 
Page 23:
the Xbee will stop transmission/Reveive while the pin 9 (pin RQ) is on HIGH position. 
So the Xbee will not read the data to send it to the coordinator. It's like the Xbee is disconnected from the network.

So, basically it's a no :S

it's more useful for end device which only send data and allow you to activate it when you need it.

If you add some information about you project, we can found a solution with you ;)

hope i've help you, Thana